# JSF and Phonegap

Tags: jsf, cordova, native

I am a new Java developer and I would like to develop a JSF mobile application. I know I could use JSF 2.0 together with Richfaces, IceFaces or PrimeFaces to develop my app, but I think it would run only on the server and I am not sure if it would have access to offline storage and device’s camera, required by the application.

**Question:** is it possible to use Phonegap or a similar framework to make my JSF mobile app go native?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JSF and phonegap can be used together. Phonegap's app is HTML/CSS/javascript app, which doesn't require server. It is client only. JSF app is client-server: application logic mostly located on server and all html generated by server. You can't port it to phone now.

If you need access phone's stuff: offline storage, camera, you can create app in phonegap, sends ajax request to your server. Server can provide some API and you can write it in java. You don't need JSF in this case.  Google for REST and Spring for java web services. Or better check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Primeface Mobile.  It is a UI toolkit for writing JSF web applications tailored for mobile clients.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf

Comment: The problem with PrimeFaces is that the app will run only on the server. I am also afraid that Offline-caching and access to the camera will not be possible with PrimeFaces.